Condition for equality of two integrals
If we have two integrals that are equal
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}F(x)dx=\int_{x_0'}^{x_1'}H(x)dx$$
Where $x_1-x_0=x_1'-x_0'$. What is the condition that a function $g$ must have to make
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}g(F(x))dx=\int_{x_0'}^{x_1'}g(H(x))dx$$?
In particular,the function $g$ I'm working with is
$$g(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$
